# flutter app will not run, cannot work out why

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I have an android app that I am porting to iphone.   Had it almost ready, ran 30+ compiles onto my test iphone while making changes etc.   The very last compile I needed to run before submitting to the store failed.

I have spent countless hours on this, down many different paths.  Started with a corrupt file in the lockdown folder, moved through no longer having a certifcate keychain entry and now finally I am in a place where I no longer even know what is wrong, so I am desperate for some assistance with this.

Here is the output of my flutter doctor:

```
dev@Users-Mac my_app % flutter doctor -v

[!] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.4, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E224g,
locale en-AU)
• Flutter version 1.7.8+hotfix.4 at /Users/dev/flutter
• Framework revision 20e59316b8 (7 months ago), 2019-07-18
20:04:33 -0700
• Engine revision fee001c93f
• Dart version 2.4.0
✗ Downloaded executables cannot execute on host.
See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/6207 for more information


[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
Install Android Studio from:
https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK
components.
(or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed
instructions).
If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set
ANDROID_HOME to that location.
You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Xcode 11.3.1, Build version 11C504
• CocoaPods version 1.7.5
[✓] iOS tools - develop for iOS devices
• ios-deploy 1.10.0
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
• Android Studio not found; download from
https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
(or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed
instructions).

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
• iPhone • 39c7fe9b4c604a4bb9340e269626a • ios • iOS
13.3.1
! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

And this is what I am getting from flutter run -v now:

The TL;DR section could possibly be this bit here?  This is the same error I get trying to launch out of Xcode too, but as I say I was able to run this app many times previously and I have added nothing:

```
/Users/dev/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_dynamic_links-.4.0+4/ios/Classes/FirebaseDynamicLinksPlugin.m:2:
9: fatal error: 'UserAgent.h' file not found
#import "UserAgent.h"
^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Larger output is here, but I cannot inclulde all of it due to character limit:

```
    /Users/dev/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-
0.11.1+7/ios/Classes/FirebaseAuthPlugin.m:6:9: fatal error:
'UserAgent.h' file not found
#import "UserAgent.h"
^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
ProcessInfoPlistFile
/Users/dev/Projects/my_app/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/fi
rebase_admob/firebase_admob.framework/Info.plist
/Users/dev/Projects/my_app/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\
Files/firebase_admob/firebase_admob-Info.plist (in target
'firebase_admob' from project 'Pods')
cd /Users/dev/Projects/my_app/ios/Pods
builtin-infoPlistUtility
/Users/dev/Projects/my_app/ios/Pods/Target\
Support\ Files/firebase_admob/firebase_admob-Info.plist
-producttype com.apple.product-type.framework
-expandbuildsettings -format binary -platform iphoneos
-requiredArchitecture arm64 -o
/Users/dev/Projects/my_app/build/ios/Debug-iphoneo
s/firebase_admob/firebase_admob.framework/Info.plist
** BUILD FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
CompileC
/Users/dev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gclpd
pnsdqsmkseciycckchipfzl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.bu
ild/Debug-iphoneos/firebase_dynamic_links.build/Objects-nor
mal/arm64/FirebaseDynamicLinksPlugin.o
/Users/dev/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_dyna
mic_links-0.4.0+4/ios/Classes/FirebaseDynamicLinksPlugin.m
normal arm64 objective-c
com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
CompileC
/Users/dev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gclpd
pnsdqsmkseciycckchipfzl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.bu
ild/Debug-iphoneos/firebase_core.build/Objects-normal/arm64
/FirebaseCorePlugin.o
/Users/dev/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core
-0.4.0+9/ios/Classes/FirebaseCorePlugin.m normal arm64
objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
CompileC
/Users/dev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gclpd
pnsdqsmkseciycckchipfzl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.bu
ild/Debug-iphoneos/firebase_auth.build/Objects-normal/arm64
/FirebaseAuthPlugin.o
/Users/dev/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth
-0.11.1+7/ios/Classes/FirebaseAuthPlugin.m normal arm64
objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(3 failures)
[ +74 ms] Running Xcode build... (completed in 6,564ms, longer than
expected)


[ +28 ms] Failed to build iOS app
[ +1 ms] Error output from Xcode build:
↳
[ +2 ms] ** BUILD FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
CompileC
/Users/dev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runnergclpdpnsdqsmkseciycck
chipfzl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/
firebase_dyna
mic_links.build/Objects-normal/arm64/FirebaseDynamicLinksPlugin.o
/Users/dev/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/
firebase_dynamic_links-0.4.0+
4/ios/Classes/FirebaseDynamicLinksPlugin.m normal arm64
objective-c
com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
CompileC
/Users/dev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runnergclpdpnsdqsmkseciycck
chipfzl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/
firebase_core
.build/Objects-normal/arm64/FirebaseCorePlugin.o
/Users/dev/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.4.0+9/
ios/Cla
sses/FirebaseCorePlugin.m normal arm64 objective-c
com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
CompileC
/Users/dev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runnergclpdpnsdqsmkseciycck
chipfzl/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/
firebase_auth
.build/Objects-normal/arm64/FirebaseAuthPlugin.o
/Users/dev/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.11.1+7/
ios/Cl
asses/FirebaseAuthPlugin.m normal arm64 objective-c
com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(3 failures)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only fix I have been able to find for this is to run xcode and choose to open the target, rather than the project.   The software will then know how to find all these header files without issue.

It doesn't seem like a proper fix to me, looks like really poor backend coding.   But since they are not doing anything to fix up their mess, use this method for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

use Like this

```
dependencies: 
  firebase_auth: 0.15.3
dependency_overrides:
  firebase_core: 0.4.4
```